# User Exit for Reason of Rejection VA01

Tags: abap, sap-erp

My requirement is to make sure only main item and free goods is able to clear reason of rejection when selected together, if not main item will be rejected using rejected reason on free goods. The issues is SAP default program always overide any changes i did. I Found this user exit **MV45AFZZ** under **FORM USEREXIT_MOVE_FIELD_TO_VBAK** but it's not working. Would you please help.

My Code

```
FORM USEREXIT_MOVE_FIELD_TO_VBAK.
ENHANCEMENT 1  ZFREEBIES_REJ_CHECK_ON_CHANGE.    "active version

   DATA:    lv_uepos TYPE vbap-uepos,
            lv_abgru TYPE vbap-abgru,
            lw_xvbap TYPE vbapvb.

   LOOP at xvbap WHERE pstyv = 'TANN'.
     READ TABLE xvbap INTO lw_xvbap WITH KEY posnr = xvbap-uepos.
     IF sy-subrc EQ 0.
       xvbap-updkz = 'U'.
       CLEAR xvbap-grpkz.
       lv_uepos = xvbap-uepos.
       IF ( lw_xvbap-abgru ne xvbap-abgru AND xvbap-abgru NE '' ).
        CASE xvbap-vbeln.
        WHEN ''.
           MODIFY xvbap TRANSPORTING abgru grpkz WHERE posnr = xvbap-posnr.
           MODIFY xvbap TRANSPORTING abgru grpkz WHERE posnr = lv_uepos.
        WHEN OTHERS.
           MODIFY xvbap TRANSPORTING abgru updkz grpkz WHERE posnr = xvbap-posnr.
           MODIFY xvbap TRANSPORTING abgru updkz grpkz WHERE posnr = lv_uepos.
       ENDCASE.
       ENDIF.
     ENDIF.
     ENDLOOP.


ENDENHANCEMENT.
ENDFORM.
```

Figure

```
Initial Value :
main item  = Rejected
free goods = Rejected.

User Change:
Main Item  = Cleared.
Free goods = Rejected.

Sap Result:
Main Item = Cleared
Free Goods = Cleared.

Expected Result :
Main Item = Rejected
Free Goods = Rejected
```

Comment: It seems illogic to use `USEREXIT_MOVE_FIELD_TO_VBAK` if you want to update `VBAP`. Why don't you use `USEREXIT_MOVE_FIELD_TO_VBAP` ?

Comment: thx for reply sandra,

It seem illogical but i tried with move to **USEREXIT_MOVE_FIELD_TO_VBAP** already, i put break point there and none was caught whenever i change the reason of rejection.
USEREXIT_MOVE_FIELD_TO_VBAP only caught when **new line was inserted to vbap**

Comment: At what moment you wanna fire your check? During order creation? Changing? When user specifies reason for rejection?